# Matlab batch vs createjob

Tags: matlab

I'm using the following `wrapper` code (shortened) to submit an batch job (stored in the `my_parjob.m` file) to the matlab cluster.

```
files = { .... list of attached files ... };
cluster = parcluster();  %returns my cluster object
job = batch(cluster,'my_parjob','CaptureDiary',true,'AutoAttachFiles',true,'AttachedFiles',files,'Matlabpool',cluster.NumWorkers-1,'CurrentFolder','/path/to/my/job');
wait(job);
```

The code works and uses the `batch` function for, create a job with maximum available workers and run the job. (The `my_parjob.m` contains my program with `parfor`).

Could someone explain me a difference and/or similarity between the `batch` command and the `createJob` + `createTask` + `submit`? Is the `batch` only a sort of shorthand for the following?

```
cluster = parcluster();
job = createJob(cluster);
t = createTask(j, ????); % ???
submit(job);
wait(job);
```

I'm trying to understand the batching concepts in Matlab by reading thru [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/batch-processing.html) and the [detailed job control](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/index.html#customized-jobs-and-cluster-access) and [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/job-and-task-creation.html) but without much success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `batch` is basically a convenience short-hand for the `createJob`/`createTask` workflow. It doesn't allow the full control of those APIs, but it is much simpler to use.

EDIT: taking your example code:

```
cluster = parcluster();
job = batch(cluster,...                  %# 1
    'my_parjob',...                      %# 2
    'CaptureDiary',true,...              %# 3
    'AutoAttachFiles',true,...           %# 4
    'AttachedFiles',files,...            %# 5
    'Matlabpool',cluster.NumWorkers-1,...%# 6
    'CurrentFolder','/path/to/my/job');  %# 7
```

Each of the lines mostly corresponds to a parameter either to `createJob` or `createTask`. There are a couple of things that don't translate perfectly though - in your case, you're requesting to run a MATLAB *script* called `'my_parjob.m'`. Unfortunately, `createJob`/`createTask` work only with functions, so you'll need a function called `my_parfcn.m` which does the same thing. Also, there are two different variants of `createJob`  - the other one is called `createCommunicatingJob` - and that corresponds to a `batch` job with the `'Matlabpool'` argument specified. So, putting it all together, you end up with this

```
cluster = parcluster();
job = createCommunicatingJob(cluster, ...     %# 1
    'AutoAttachFiles', true, ...              %# 4
    'AttachedFiles', files, ...               %# 5
    'NumWorkers', cluster.NumWorkers);        %# 6
task = createTask(job, ...
    @my_parfcn, 1, {}, ...                    %# 2 Task function, nargsout, input arguments 
    'CaptureDiary', true);  .                 %# 3
submit(job);
```

There's no equivalent to `'CurrentFolder'`, so you'll have to handle that inside `my_parfcn`.

Comment: Thank you very much, could you please show me, _(or point me to some resource)_ how achieve the **same** functionality with `createJob` + `createTask` + `submit` as with the `batch` command? My first problem is (as it shown in the question) is, what to write to the `createTask` line for getting maximum number of available workers for my `my_parjob` as like in the `batch`. I need to learn those extended controls to achieve queueing more jobs in the cluster for later sequential processing. AFAIK, this can't be done with the `batch` command alone.